JWT ASP.NET Core MVC problem with authorization when check role
There was a problem with authentication, which was solved here. Now there is a problem with authorization, if I set the parameter Roles, I get an error.
Program.cs:
namespace MySteamDBMetacritic
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((options) =>
                options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole<int>>(options =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    RoleClaimType = ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]!))
                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                        var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { message = "Authentication failed" });
                        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
                    }
                };
                options.TokenHandlers.Add(new BearerTokenHandler());
            });

            builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AdminPolicy", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
                options.AddPolicy("UserPolicy", policy => policy.RequireRole("User"));
            });

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 1024 * 1024 * 20;
            });

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

                try
                {
                    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
                    var rolesManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>>>();
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                    await RoleInitializer.InitializeAsync(context, userManager, rolesManager);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
                }
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Game}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

The accounts are create in AccountController.cs, the admin is created in RoleInitializer.cs. This controller is an example of where the error occurs UsersController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MySteamDBMetacritic.Models;
using MySteamDBMetacritic.ViewModels;

namespace MySteamDBMetacritic.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        UserManager<User> _userManager;

        public UsersController(UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public IActionResult Index() => View(_userManager.Users.ToList());

        public IActionResult Create() => View();

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateUserViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = new User { Email = model.Email, UserName = model.UserName };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
        {
            User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());

            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            EditUserViewModel model = new EditUserViewModel { Id = user.Id, Email = user.Email, UserName = user.UserName };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(EditUserViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id.ToString());

                if (user != null)
                {
                    user.Email = model.Email;
                    user.UserName = model.UserName;

                    var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());

            if (user != null)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}

AccountController.cs
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AccountController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = new User { Email = model.Email, UserName = model.UserName };

                if (_userManager.Users
                                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == user.Email) != default(User))
                {
                    return View(model);
                }

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
                    return Json(new { token = Token(model.UserName, model.Password), returnUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Game") });
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            return View(new LoginViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Json(new { token = ((JsonResult)Token(model.UserName, model.Password)).Value, returnUrl = model.ReturnUrl});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json(new { token = ((JsonResult)Token(model.UserName, model.Password)).Value, returnUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Game") });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username or password");
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Game");
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(int id)
        {
            User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());

            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            ChangePasswordViewModel model = new ChangePasswordViewModel { Id = user.Id, Email = user.Email };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id.ToString());

                if (user != null)
                {
                    var _passwordValidator = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IPasswordValidator<User>)) as IPasswordValidator<User>;
                    var _passwordHasher = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IPasswordHasher<User>)) as IPasswordHasher<User>;

                    IdentityResult result = await _passwordValidator.ValidateAsync(_userManager, user, model.NewPassword);

                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        user.PasswordHash = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, model.NewPassword);
                        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "User is missing");
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        public IActionResult Token(string username, string password)
        {
            var identity = GetIdentity(username, password).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            if (identity == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { errorText = "Invalid username or password." });
            }

            var now = DateTime.Now;

            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    audience: _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    notBefore: now,
                    claims: identity.Claims,
                    expires: now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(double.Parse(_configuration["Jwt:ExpiresMinutes"]))),
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"])), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
            var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

            var response = new
            {
                access_token = encodedJwt,
                username = identity.Name
            };

            return Json(response);
        }

        private async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GetIdentity(string username, string password)
        {
            User user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, string.Join(',',_userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result))
                };

                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Token", 
                                  ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType,
                                  ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);

                return claimsIdentity;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

I have checked, the role is assigned.
RoleInitializer, execute every start program, GetRoleAsync return "Admin"
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using MySteamDBMetacritic.Db;
using MySteamDBMetacritic.Models;

namespace MySteamDBMetacritic.Classes
{
    public class RoleInitializer
    {
        public static async Task InitializeAsync(ApplicationDbContext _context, UserManager<User> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>> roleManager)
        {
            string adminEmail = "admin@gmail.com";
            string password = "aA12345!";

            if (await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin") == null)
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<int>("Admin"));
            }

            if (await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("User") == null)
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<int>("User"));
            }

            if (await userManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin") == null)
            {
                User admin = new User { Email = adminEmail, UserName = "Admin" };
                IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(admin, password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                     await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(admin, "Admin");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                User? admin = await userManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin");
                var result = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(admin);

                if (!result.Contains("Admin"))
                {
                    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(admin, "Admin");
                }
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}


I did a little research and didn't find anything that could help me, I just added to
TokenValidationParameters RoleClaimType = ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType 

and it didn't help me.
When I create a JWT token all is good:

But when I check HttpContext, there is no "role" claim:


In your code after Create(CreateUserViewModel model)  method, I haven't seen that you are assigning the role to the newly created user.

don't look at the methods in the UserController (not completed), I showed this so that you can see in which controller the problem is, in the RoleInitializer the Admin user is created, a record with it and a role are also created in the database, also added to the UserRole table. The data is stored in a JWT token, there is a role, I send the token as a response, it is correct, when I receive the token from the JWT it is also correct, but due to some problem ASP does not take the role field from it.


JWT ASP.NET Core MVC problem with authorization when check role. But when I check HttpContext, there is no "role" claim:

After a lot of investigations and testing I have founded the issue within your project.
I have gone through your csproj file and I've noticed, you are using <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="7.6.3" />
and <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.7" />
Together, this is the main resason for experiencing the unexpected behaviour in accessing the token claims which creating conflict and compatibility problem between the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens package and the other packages related to JWT and identity handling within the project.
In order to resolve the issue just remove the <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="7.6.3" /> from your csproj file.
Your csproj should as following:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="6.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="6.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="6.6.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Output:


Note: You might not need the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens package directly, as the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer package already includes it as a dependency. All of your existing code seem correct and no additional modification required. I have tested all of your scenario and eveything working as expected.

I had a problem with token authentication due to a format mismatch (IDX14100), but jwt.io said everything was correct. I solved this problem by writing BearerTokenHandler, it receives the correct token as input, but after calling JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken() it does not transfer the role claim from jwt to validatedToken https://i.sstatic.net/YuFnSkx7.png. Description of this problem in my other question link. as far as I understand the decision was wrong.

can you please download my project from github and try to resolve problem exactly for my project?

I have gone through your project and it seems the issue is strange, token has the claims but when it comes to Users controller Index I have checked the claims is not there.

What could be the reason in this case? I’ve already read a lot of articles and haven’t found a solution that will help me?

There may be something wrong with the library versions and I was lucky to download the buggy version.

Finally, I was able to figure out the issue, and updated the answer for you, please try and I hope it would resolve your issue.

Thank you very much, all works as i need, but how could I know that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer already includes Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens if nuget (or I don't understand something) in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer dependencies does not specify Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens? I'm asking to avoid such a stupid mistake in the future.

Actually, its hard to explain, because there's no specific way to know but while you would  need any specific nuget package you could check the prerequisite of that. Also release note can be seen. But yeah, I had to check lot of stuff to conclude this outcome. However, I am not sure why have you added that package since its not required for your scenario.

This is all because I looked at the JWT Token implementation and the articles I found used this, maybe it was for .net 6 or it was not updated information. I would also like to ask for advice, I want to make sure that after logging in, the user is redirected to some link, but my login method sends a JWT Token and the link to which the redirection will be made, as a result the JS script does fetch and inject response into login page, I don't know if I can somehow send a JWT Token and do a redirect using RedirectToAction()?

As this issue has been resolved, so its better to not extent this conversation, but as you have used js in client side to you might need to use  window.location.href = '/Users/AccessDenied' in order to redirect. However, if you have any other concern, you could post new question, thus, I could check if I can assist you there.
